# Why does Postgres refuse to start as service?

Tags: windows, postgresql, installation

I try to install Postgres on Windows (Server 2003). Both versions I tried (8.3, 8.4) fail at the end of the installation because the service cannot be started. I tried with different users for the service without success.

Any ideas anyone?

Comment: Uninstall Windows (Server 2003), install the GNU/Linux distro of your choice, apt-get or yum install postgres to your heart's content.

Comment: There should be some log files in the data directory that could provide some insight.

Comment: @Conrad: One minute waiting for the hint on installing Linux - I've expected this within *seconds*. Even though: Very helpful! BTW: That's not an option. An actually I successfully installed Postgres on Linux, Mac, Windows XY a lot of times before..

Comment: Well, what error do you get?   What is there in the Event Viewer?

Comment: @Jordan, log files in the data directory, or entry in the Event Viewer.

Answer (score 1):

It's usually a permissions issue. Check that the installer set up the permissions correctly for the user running the service (usually "postgres").